# How configure inky-rb in rail API-only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, zurb-ink

Im trying to install the inky-rb gem to use the foundation-email themes in rails API-Only. This api only read/send data but we want to send emails for user from her.

I aready added the gem

```
# Preprocessor for email HTML to convert components in table structure https://get.foundation/emails/docs/gem-guide.html

gem 'inky-rb', require: 'inky'

# Stylesheet inlining for email (used by inky)
gem 'premailer-rails'
```

but when run

```
rails g inky:install
```

And added the foundation_emails.scss the ruby on rails email preview breaks

so i aready try uncomment

```
require 'action_view/railtie'
```

in application.rb and add `config.assets.precompile += ['foundation_email.css' ]` in the same file.

but now when i go to mailers preview i recive this error

```
LoadError in Rails::MailersController#preview
cannot load such file -- sassc
```

To try solve this i tried added the gem

```
gem 'sprockets', '~> 4.0'
gem 'sassc-rails'
```

but din't worked

Comment: If you have found a solution then you should not edit your question but post it as a solution. Please read [ask], [answer] and pass the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what you should do

1 - Create you mailer with

```
rails g mailer folder_name email_name
```

2 - Add the inky-rb, sassc-rails and sprockets gems in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'inky-rb', require: 'inky'    
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'premailer-rails'
gem 'sassc-rails'
```

For install the gems run bundle install and after rails s

3 - now you have to install the inky whit

```
rails g inky:install
```

OBS: This add to arquives `foundation_emails.scss` the ruby on rails email preview breaks css and a new mailer layout

4 - in `aplication.rb` uncomment require `sprockets/railtie` and add after the line config.api_only = true

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( foundation_mails.css )
```

you al so need to add a manifest.js inside assets/config

```
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

5 - Now in views/folder_name_mailer you change the file name, from email_name.html.erb to email_name.html.inky and add one layout like this one

```
<container>
  <columns>  
    <spacer size="16"></spacer>
       <h4 class="text-center"> This Works \0/ </h4>
    </columns>
  </row>
</container>
```

6- you can watch your changes in `localhost:3000/rails/mailers/folder_name_mailer/email_name.html`

This tutorial for full Ruby and Rails helped me alot to fix this problem Mail Previews and [Templates Tutorial in Youtube](https://youtu.be/lUFgOiYP9yM)